# Exclude a class within a clickable class

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure (`.holder` has a 40px padding so lots of room around element `.classA`):

```
<div class="holder">
  <a href="/path/to/file.html" class="classA">Hello</div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on `.holder` something happens, but I want to stop that click from firing if the user clicks element `.classA`

This is what I currently use, but I want to say when `.holder` is clicked but not `.classA`

```
$(document).on('click', '.holder', function() {
  modClose();
});
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, although similar:

```
$(document).on('click', '.holder', function(e) {
        if($(e.target).hasClass('classA')) return;
        modClose();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just stop the event propagation when `.classA` is clicked:

```
$('.classA').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation()
});

$(document).on('click', '.holder', function() {
    modClose();
});
```

From jQuery documentation about [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

> **Description**: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `target` of the event:

http://jsfiddle.net/KwcAj/

```
$(document).on('click', '.holder', function(e) {
  if (e.target != this) { 
    console.log('stop');
    return;
  }       
  console.log('go');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check targets className

```
$(document).on('click', '.holder', function (e) {
  if (e.target.className.indexOf('classA') == -1) {
    modClose();
  }
});
```